# Plesk website via local IP

Tags: php, iis, plesk

I run Plesk Panel on my local Windows web server which works just fine but I want to add a website that will only be used on my local network.

I have added it in the usual way and it works fine via it's domain however I want to know if it's possible to execute it via a local IP instead of the domain name.

The main reason for this is that I hope it will speed up access for local users by avoiding DNS etc.

So currently it's: http://subdomain.domain.com
but I want to use: http://123.123.123.123/website (or similar)

Is this possible? I appreciate it probably isn't done from within Plesk.

The site requires PHP if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days hunting its actually remarkably simple and can be done through Plesk.

Tools & Settings > IP Addresses

Select servers IP and assign the relevant domain to it from the drop down.